# tcsh 6 gives error for quote marks

Tags: tcsh, setenv

I run software that generates following script.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f
setenv 'CDS_LIC_FILE' '5280@sjflex5'
setenv 'LM_LICENSE_FILE' '5280@mammoth.xyz.xyz'
```

This works fine on RedHat EE50.

On RedHat EE60 it is broken and gives following error.

```
setenv: Variable name must begin with a letter.
```

I have no control over the script generation process nor can I change the RedHat EE60 installation on the targeted machine. Any other way to patch this and make it work?

Thanks,
Gert

Comment: Since environment variable names can't contain special characters, there's no need to quote them.

Comment: Most likely something changed between tcsh versions 6.14.00 (which accepts `setenv 'foo' 'bar'` and 6.18.00 (which rejects it with 
`setenv: Variable name must begin with a letter`".

Comment: @Barmar The OP has no control over the prog which produces the quotes.

Comment: Or alias setenv (and de-quote the first arg before calling setenv proper).

Comment: The change occurred between release 6.17.00 and 6.17.04. The entry in the "Fixes" file says "49. PR/113: Don't allow illegal variable names to be set". (I haven't absolutely confirmed that that's what did it, but it seems likely.)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with character classes in regular expressions but you'll get the idea and can add completeness and elegance ;-):

```
software_that_generates_following_script \
  | sed "s/setenv[ \t]* '\([0-9A-Za-z_]*\)'/setenv \1/" \
  > generated_shell_script
```

Perhaps that helps...